# use yytext in bison code

Tags: c, bison, lex

When I trying to compile my code in yacc&lex I get this error:
[image: this error]

yacc Code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define YYSTYPE struct node*
typedef struct node{
    char *token;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
} node;
node* mknode(char* token, node *left, node *right);
void Printtree(node *tree);
int yyerror();
%}
%token NUM PLUS MINUS
%left PLUS MINUS
%%
S:exp {printf("OK\n"); Printtree($1);};
exp:exp PLUS exp {$$=mknode("+",$1,$3);}
    | exp MINUS exp{$$=mknode("-",$1,$3);}
    | NUM {$$=mknode(yytext, NULL, NULL);};
%%
#include "lex.yy.c"
int main(){
    return yyparse();
}
node *mknode (char *token, node *left, node *right){
    node *newnode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    char *newstr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(token)+1);
    strcpy (newstr, token);
    newnode->left=left;
    newnode->right=right;
    newnode->token=newstr;
    return newnode;
}
void Printtree(node* tree){
    printf("%s\n", tree->token);
    if (tree->left)
        Printtree(tree->left);
    if (tree->right)
        Printtree(tree->right);
}
int yyerror(){
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and the lex Code

```
%%
[0-9]+ return NUM;
\+ return PLUS;
\- return MINUS;
%%
```

when i trying to change the yytext to $1 is compiled but when i run the code and type for example 5+6 is saying: (segmentation fault (core dumped))

using ubuntu 64:

lex compile with flex version lex 2.6.0:

```
lex subProject.lex
```

and yacc compile with bison version bison(GNU Bison) 3.0.4:

```
yacc subProject.yacc
```

and the error maker:

```
cc subProject -o y.tab.c -ll -Ly
```

Comment: Don't post links to, or pictures of, text here. Post the text. It is a complete waste of your time, which I don't care about, and our bandwidth, which I do.

Comment: Is the '`yacc`' you're using actually Bison in disguise?  What do you get from `yacc --version`?  And is the '`lex`' you're using actually Flex in disguise?  What do you get from `lex --version`?  It may matter; original AT&T Yacc and Lex are slightly different from Bison and Flex (and note that the tag for this Flex is [tag:flex-lexer] not [tag:flex]; the other is for Adobe Flex).  And one difference is the type of `yytext`.  However, the declaration vs no declaration may be a separate issue — except that it is crucial to use the correct declaration.

Comment: I wrote that im using flex and bison but now im added the versions.

Comment: But your tags said [tag:yacc]. Fixed that for you too. But your command line says `yacc`. Please make up your mind. Please fix the image as requested too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `yytext` in grammar rules at all. It won't always have the value you think it might have. You should save it in the `yyunion` in the scanner:

```
[0-9]+ { yylval.text = strdup(yytext); return NUM; }
```

and similarly for the other rules that need it, and then use it in the parser like this:

```
| NUM {$$=mknode($1, NULL, NULL);}
```

using the usual techniques for declaring the `YYUNION` and typing the nodes.

Comment: i make those changes and now i got new error:
In function 'yylex':
request for member 'text' in somthing not a structure or union.

Comment: i use it like this: [0-9]+ { yylval = strdup(yytext); return NUM; }
and it worked thnks .

Comment: So you need to declare `text` as a member of the union, as I said above. You need to look into how to use the yyunion and how to strongly type your parse tree nodes. It will help you in the long run.